# calculus change of coordinates use fubini theorem

Tags: calculus

i have this question how can we use change of variable to find this equality :

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p}dtdx$$ $$=$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$ $$+$$ $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p} \int_{0}^{1/t}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$

Comment: The region $0<t<1/x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ is the union of the regions $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and $0<x<1/t$ for $t>1$

Comment: thanks but not really clear until now

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  So, you have it now?

Comment: not really ,,,, but i think we can use this ,, but then i don t really know how to complete......  
by fubini we have 

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p}dtdx$$ $$=$$ $$\int_{0}^{1/x}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$ $$=$$$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$ $$+$$ $$\int_{1}^{1/x}\frac{|ln(t)|^p}{|1-t|^p}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{p-1}}dxdt$$

Comment: That is not correct. The symbol $x$ is a dummy integration variable and cannot appear as an integration limit of the outer integral.

Comment: aaaahhhhh ,, yeah yeah ,, you are true this is not correct i understand now  ,,,,, but it just stays for me , your first unswer that is not really clear

Comment: if we take this union how can we find then the equality

Comment: Draw a picture of the initial integration region.  You will see that one can describe it in which $x$ is the domain and $t$ is the range, or vice-versa.  I have to call it a night;  it's nearly 1:00 a.m. here. Best of luck.

Comment: thank you very much i ll try to see it like you told me